# Recording sound of 4 USB microphones connected to Raspberry Pi and calculate TDOA

Tags: python

For my project to locate a sound source, I need to calculate the Time Difference of Arrival (TDOA) of 4 microphones.

I want to connect this 4 microphones with a powered USB Hub to my Raspberry Pi and place them about 5 meters from each other. Then I want to calculate the time of arrival of each microphone, when the sound passes the threshold (peak). Is it possible to record from 4 microphones at the same time from one raspberry pi, and is it possible to know the exact time of arrival (or difference of arrival) of the sound to each microphone?

Comment: The difference in time isn't going to be significantly different between microphones, especially at 5 meters apart. At 330 m/s a sound wave travels 5 meters in about 0.015 of a second. Depending on the microphones you might have an issue distinguishing the source sound from background noise.

Comment: Cross correlation could be a solution for this problem. Here is an example of how someone did it with microphones much closer to each other: http://ruralhacker.blogspot.nl/p/micloc.html. The first step for me is to record from 4 microphones at the same time and whenever a peak is detected, either the exact time of the peak has to be determined or directly the time difference of arrival. I really hope that I can find a solution for this.